# Utilu IE Collection IE6 crashes under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-6

I've installed Utilu IE Collection under Windows 7 64-bit, but am unable to successfully run IE6 (specifically, "Internet Explorer 6.0 (6.00.2900.2180)"). I haven't tried other versions of IE from the package, so their behavior is unknown.

It starts up fine, but the address bar isn't shown.

[image: here]

View->Toolbars shows 'Address Bar' already selected. If I try to (de-)select Address Bar in that list, it crashes:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: iexplore.exe
  Application Version:  6.0.2900.2180
  Application Timestamp:    41107b81
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_e162
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: e162
  Additional Information 2: e1625455580a00d3fda64a8cdf366fbb
  Additional Information 3: 58c7
  Additional Information 4: 58c75753c6745fad91929ab6430a83fa
```

That's not all that's wrong ('Search' pane has no contents as well, probably more), but it's the most glaring problem.

I've seen some allusions to a registry change needed to fix this, but haven't been able to find any details. Anybody?

I'm running the latest version of the collection, 1.7.0.6.

Comment: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tremendous problems with Utilu package under Win 7 myself. I ended downloading Virtual PC images from Microsoft website. You can get them **[here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en)**.